# ERROR: Permission to user/bnr.git denied to user/IntroductionToIosProgramming?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push changes to my new repository and I see error as

```
➜  xcode  git clone git@github.com:hhimanshu/bnr.git
Cloning into 'bnr'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
➜  xcode  cd bnr
➜  bnr git:(master) vi README.md 
➜  bnr git:(master) ✗ gst
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  bnr git:(master) ✗ git add README.md 
➜  bnr git:(master) ✗ git commit -m "read.me"        
[master ec737ea] read.me
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
➜  bnr git:(master) git push origin master
ERROR: Permission to hhimanshu/bnr.git denied to hhimanshu/IntroductionToIosProgramming.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do not really understand, why this repository is talking about `hhimanshu/IntroductionToIosProgramming`, this is some other repository I have

I also checked my `git config` and I see as

```
➜  bnr git:(master) git config --list                                              
user.name=Harit Himanshu
user.email=mycorrectemail@yahoo.in
push.default=matching
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:hhimanshu/bnr.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Also when I do `ssh git@github.com -v`, I see

```
Hi hhimanshu/IntroductionToIosProgramming! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Somehow my user name is set up incorrect, but my username seems right

```
git config --global user.name
Harit Himanshu
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your user.name should be:

```
user.name = hhimanshu
```

As it is a Github login here, not a descriptive user name

Edit:
When you do changes in configuration file, don't forget to first reset your last commit and perform commit again after the change